# How to implement refresh tokens in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, refresh-token

I am trying to implement refresh tokens in my angular app. I have written an http interceptor which tries to get a new access token whenever I get a 401 error. I don't know why but this doesn't work. I am still getting a 401 response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if response code is 401 then request for refresh token and wait for response after receiving response process pending requests.
[refresh token with http interceptor](https://itnext.io/angular-tutorial-implement-refresh-token-with-httpinterceptor-bfa27b966f57)

Answer (score 0):

Generate refreshToken before request if need it

```
export class HttpRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private router: Router, private service: AuthService) { }

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {

    return from(this.tokenHandler(request)).pipe(mergeMap((req: HttpRequest<any>) => {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if ([401].indexOf(err.status) != -1) {
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
            }                
            else {                    
                throw err;
            }

            return EMPTY;
        }));
    }));
}

private async tokenHandler(request: HttpRequest<any>): Promise<HttpRequest<any>> {
    if (request.url.indexOf("REFRESHTOKEN_URL") == -1) {
        await this.service.GenerateNewTokenIfNeed(); //Important this function would be async and put httpClient call to ToPromise() and await it. Save token somewhere and get from there to #token# place
    }
    else {
        //RefreshTokenRequest
    }

    const authReq = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: "Bearer #token#"
        },
    });

    return authReq;
}
```